# Unable to use Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, telerik

Using `Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin` throws the following exception
in my emulator:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.telerik.widget.list.R$id" on path`

I'm using an API25 simulator.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the package on both your shared as well as the platform (Android) project? Also, do the versions match?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Upgraded it to an answer for you, please accept! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add the same package both to your shared project as well as your platform project. In this case your Android project. Also, make sure that the versions match.

This is needed because it will work pretty similar to the wat a DependencyService or custom renderer works. You define a contract in your shared code, but it needs some platform specific stuff as well. The versions need to match in order to be sure that the method signatures etc. match.